# Could not find executable running image_view from rosrun

Tags: image-view, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been using image_view to see the contents of image topics for some time, but I encountered a problem and I have no idea what the cause is. Here's what I get when trying to check an image topic:

Command I typed:

**rosrun image_view image_view image:=/...(topic)**

Terminal output:

**[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named image_view below /opt/ros/hydro/share/image_view**

**[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files, or not executable:**

**[rosrun] /opt/ros/hydro/share/image_view**

It shouldn't be a source problem. Many other programs can run normaly.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182030/could-not-find-executable-running-image_view-from-rosrun/) by [CathIAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/10501/cathias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed it using Debian try deleting it and reinstalling it, maybe it will be the fastest way to solve your problem.

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-hydro-image-view
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-image-view
```

Otherwise delete everything called image_view manually and reinstall it using apt-get.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CathIAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/10501/cathias/) on 2014-07-02**:
Reinstalling it is indeed the fastest way to solve the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try the Qt GUI plugin version of image_view.

If you're using hydro:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rqt-image-view
```

otherwise, don't forget to replace the hydro with the ros distro you're using.

Then run the executable node:

```
rosrun rqt_image_view rqt_image_view
```

At the top left corner, you can search for the image topic to listen.

For more details: [rqt_image_view](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_image_view)

---

Originally posted by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) with karma: 194 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CathIAS](https://answers.ros.org/users/10501/cathias/) on 2014-07-02**:
Thanks that's also a good choice

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-07-05**:
I love rqt plugins!  Genius!